# A reference for a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients

I have come across this identity from study of [species](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~maguiar/a.pdf). I am not posting my method but I am interested in knowing whether it arises in some other contexts as well. The identity is:

$$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{(-1)^{k+i}}{k+i} \binom{n-k}{i}=\frac{(-1)^k}{k\binom{n}{k}}$$ or equivalently

$$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-k} (-1)^{k+i} \binom{i+k-1}{i} \binom{n}{k+i}=(-1)^{k}$$

I can show these two are equivalent.Just to make it clear I am not just interested in a proof of this identity but also in the context where it arises naturally. Thanking You.

Comment: The second form looks like just a Vandermonde's identity ($\binom{i+k-1}i=\pm\binom{-k}i$ etc).

Comment: Can you show how these two are equivalent?

Comment: @robjohn Yes I can show both are equivalent but I want to know whether there is some context in combinatorics or any other part of mathematics where this identity arises naturally

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-k} (-1)^{k+i} \binom{i+k-1}{i} \binom{n}{k+i}
&=(-1)^k\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i\binom{i+k-1}i\binom n{n-k-i}\\
&=(-1)^k\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^{2i}\binom{-k}i\binom n{n-k-i}
\qquad\text{using upper negation}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n-k}{n-k}
\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad \;\quad \text{using Vandermonde}\\
&=(-1)^k\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

To prove the first identity, we can use the [Heaviside Method for Partial Fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) to expand
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{k\binom{n}{k}}
&=\frac{(n-k)!}{k\,\underbrace{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+(n-k))}_{n!/k!}}\\[6pt]
&=\left.\frac{(n-k)!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+(n-k))}\right|_{x=k}\\[12pt]
&=\left.\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac1{x+i}\frac{(-1)^i(n-k)!}{i!(n-k-i)!}\right|_{x=k}\\[12pt]
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{k+i}\binom{n-k}{i}
\end{align}
$$
Multiplying by $(-1)^k$ gives the first identity.